# mxgraph: I would like to add a button to disable/enable the graph and toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, mxgraph

I tried to disable the graph by not allowing the cells on graph with follow code.
`graph.setCellsSelectable(false);`
but it is not working, still can select cell, (only disabled resizing)

And for the toolbar to be disabled, I tried to remove or replace ondrag event, is that correct? In theory I think mxgraph has their own event handler for dragging of toolbar item.

```
mx_toolbar.appendChild(
    mxUtils.button("Disable/Enable", function() {
         document.querySelectorAll('.toolbar > button').addEventListener(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault()
             return false;
         });
    }
)
```

Hope your help. I dont mind as long as it is working solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing or modifying the event handler, you can simply overlay the area you want to disable along with css.

```
      var toolbarContainer = document.querySelector(".toolbar");
      var overlay = document.querySelector(".toolbar-overlay")

      if (!overlay) {
        overlay = document.createElement('div')
        overlay.className = 'toolbar-overlay'
        toolbarContainer.appendChild(overlay)
      } else {        
        overlay.parentNode.removeChild(overlay)
      }
```

Here is css for the overlay div

```
.toolbar-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}
```

- Note: You should make sure the parent div of the overlay div must positioned as relative to make this css working!

Comment: overlaying divs is not part of mxgraph stuff but it works, anyway. hope you help me find better solution if dont mind.